# Why ng-model is required for ng-options directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-options="i for i in [1,2,3]"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this markup, `options` are not populated in `select`. When i provide `ng-model` along with `ng-options` it works as expected.

Why `ng-model` is required for the `ng-options` to populate the options?

Answer (score 1):

`ngOptions` needs model in order to determine which option should be selected by default or which model to write selected object/value when selection changes.

If there was no `ngModel` directive, it would be difficult to access selected value, and it potentially lead to bad-practice code when people either query DOM to determine the value or write their own directives for this purpose. In both cases this is not ideal as this type of things is the key idea of Angular form elements directives.

Also don't forget that `ngOptions` in conjunction with `ngModel` allow developer to bind entire objects as the "value" of select elements, which would be tricky without `ngModel`.

Finally, if for some reason one doesn't want to have any model on select (although it makes little sense), it's possible to render options with `ngRepeat`.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation about `ng-options`. I understand the usage and advantages of `ng-options`. `options` with `ng-repeat` will not enforce any restriction about `ng-model`. Why to enforce this restriction with `ng-options`. Why can't it just evaluate the expression and populate the options?

Comment: I think this is design decision. It just doesn't make sense to duplicate concerns. `ngRepeat` already can render options if you want. However `ngOptions` should be used for more flexible and effective work with model. It would be very easy to allow `ngOptions` to work without `ngModel`, but it would require couple of ugly `if` conditions in the code. Why, if you already can use `ngRepeat`.

Comment: It's an interesting thought. They could have created an empty object and set ngModelCtrl to that  in the link if ?ngModel returned null instead of exit out. The documentation does say that the benefit of ngOptions is less scopes created.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no model bound to the select, after choosing an option where would the selection be written out to?

As for the reason why the options are not displayed you can see the source code:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L355

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    terminal: true,
    require: ['select', '?ngModel'],
    link: function(scope, selectElement, attr, ctrls) {

      // if ngModel is not defined, we don't need to do anything
      var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[1];
      if (!ngModelCtrl) return;
```

The link function short cuts out and all the render functions are not created.

Comment: Just for the case of a scenario, I don't want to update the model, I want to post the data using form submit. I have gone through the source code and posted this question. What might be the reason for adding such a condition?

Comment: Please note that this is beta code (1.4). Currently the functionality of `ngOptions` is incorporated into the `select` directive.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> ngOptions should be used when the  model needs to be bound to a non-string value

The very point of `ngOptions` is to provide values for the model, not to merely render `option` elements. Therefore it doesn't make sense to be used without `ngModel`.